# Solr 8.11 giving "ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately" in cloud mode while starting with hybris server

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrcloud, solrclient

I am using solr 8.11 with Hybris 2205.7, sapmachine-jdk-17.0.6

Using solr in Cloud mode

While starting Local hybris server getting the below issue and its stuck there only

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqACv.png)

Below are my  solr related properties in local.properties

```
`# Solr Cloud settings\`
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false
solrserver.instances.cloud.autostart=true

solrserver.instances.cloud.ssl.enabled=false
solrserver.instances.cloud.ssl.keyStorePassword=
solrserver.instances.cloud.ssl.trustStorePassword=
solrserver.instances.cloud.zk.prop.urlScheme=http
solrserver.failOnError=true
solrserver.forceRestart=true`
```

If anybody faced this issue or if have any solution, will be helpful